# buttons wont add to view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, for-loop

I want to create a row with 4 buttons, the loop is doing what it should do, and it only enters the if statement 4 times as it should, but when the view pop's out, I can see only one button on it.

Why is that? am I doing something wrong?

```
btnFrame = 18;
for (int i = 0; i < [arrImages count]; i++)
{
    if (btnFrame <= 237)
    {
        NSLog(@"%i",btnFrame);
        UIButton * tempBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        tempBtn.frame = CGRectMake(btnFrame, 20, 65, 65);
        [tempBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button%i",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:tempBtn];
        btnFrame = btnFrame + 73;
    }
}
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: Where are you putting this code?

Comment: ViewDidLoad, actually it was something else unrelated to this thread. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This code works as intended.  As rdelmar asked, where are you putting this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think when your viewWillDisappear at that time this view will cleared so do bellow thing....
 if you crete one method in which you just paste your above code and then when yourViewController appear at that time call your method try this...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self SetButton];    
}

-(void)setButton{

btnFrame = 18;
    for (int i = 0; i < [arrImages count]; i++)
    {
        if (btnFrame <= 237)
        {
            NSLog(@"%i",btnFrame);
            UIButton * tempBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            tempBtn.frame = CGRectMake(btnFrame, 20, 65, 65);
            [tempBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button%i",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.view addSubview:tempBtn];
            btnFrame = btnFrame + 73;
        }
    }
}
```

hope this help you....
:)